# Hopefully simple bootstrap question: Bootstrap column stacking weirdly on safari desktop?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

So I've been using bootstrap for a while, I've got a super simple grid setup that's working perfectly fine on Chrome/Firefox, but is stacking improperly in Safari:

[image: Display issue]

Here's the markup, which I really can't see anything wrong with! Also visible live at www.inspiringtravelcompany.co.uk in case you're looking at any containing divs.

```
 <div class="w-100 pb-5" style="background-color:#f7f7f7">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 order-2 order-md-1">
                    <p class="fs-20 mb-2 ChronicleDeckSemiBold" style="line-height:1.3;">
                        You may have seen us recently during your favourite television programmes – and if not we’d love to share our brand new video with you.
                    </p>
                    <p class="fs-14 mb-2 ChronicleDeck">
                        Take a look, and you’ll spot some of our most popular destinations and favourite bucket list spots around the world.
                    </p>
                    <p class="fs-14 mb-2 ChronicleDeck">
                        Here at the Inspiring Travel Company we specialise in bespoke, personalised and tailor-made holidays around the world to the most amazing places; so whether you’re after a relaxing ‘fly and flop’ break or an intrepid tour, a bucket list safari or a trip to catch the world’s premier sporting events, our Travel Specialists are ready and waiting to offer first-hand insight.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 order-1 order-md-2 mb-4 mb-md-0">
                    <iframe class="w-100" width="640" height="385" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/x5sqxiO_muk">
                    </iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I just don't get what the problem is!

Comment: This could be a new bug. It seems to be tied to the `order` property.